# Flask - SQLAlchemy : Code to check the username and password

Tags: python, authentication, flask, sqlalchemy

I am doing a Flask-login system(by not using inbuilt LoginManager).
I have a query to check the username and password which is :

```
 query = s.query(Users).filter(Users.email.in_([POST_email]), Users.password.in_([POST_PASSWORD]) )
 result = query.first()
```

This query is not working. It returns None in the console. Please give a query to check whether the data given in the forms match with the database values.

**

1. Here Users is the Data Model.
2. email and password are two columns
3. POST_email and POST_password are two values that are received from forms
4. s is the instance of Session
       s = Session()

**

This is the function code.

```
def do_admin_login():
   POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
   POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])

   Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
   s = Session()
   query = s.query(Users).filter(Users.email.in_([POST_USERNAME]), Users.password.in_([POST_PASSWORD]) )
   result = query.first()
   if result:
       session['logged_in'] = True
   else:
       flash('wrong password!')
return home()
```

The

```
POST_USERNAME
```

and

```
 POST_PASSWORD
```

contain the values that are received from the forms in HTML page. I use Postgres database.

Comment: Why are you using `in_` instead of `==`?

Comment: @dim I saw the usage of

     `in_`

in an  example. So I used it here.

Comment: You can try using ==  and if you are storing encrypted password in your database then your str(password) can not work..you can use hashlib for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
query = s.query(Users).filter(Users.email==POST_USERNAME, Users.password==POST_PASSWORD)
```